# Onde colocar a regra da View Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, viewmodel

Preciso criar uma View Model para usar na tela.

Estou com dúvida onde colocar a regra de botões serem habilitados ou não.

Pensei nessa implementação, gostaria de saber se é a melhor forma. Outra ideia que tive foi colocar o conteúdo do construtor em uma classe de `Business`.

```
public class ApoQueueVM
{
    public ApoQueueVM(ApoQueue apoQueue, ApoFileBL apoFileBL)
    {
        this.EnableExport = apoQueue.Status == ApoQueueStatus.Gerado.ToString() || apoQueue.Status == ApoQueueStatus.Enviado.ToString();
        this.KeyFigure = apoQueue.KeyFigure;
        this.PathFileGenerated = apoFileBL.GetFullPathApo(apoQueue, true);
    }


    public string KeyFigure { get; set; }
    public bool HaveInconsistencies { get; set; }
    public string PathFileGenerated { get; set; }
    public bool EnableExport { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parece ser uma boa abordagem no construtor.

Adicionalmente, eu faria o construtor da classe sem parâmetros ser privado, para evitar outra forma de inicialização da classe que não seja esta:

```
public class ApoQueueVM
{
    private ApoQueueVM() { }

    public ApoQueueVM(ApoQueue apoQueue, ApoFileBL apoFileBL)
    {
        this.EnableExport = apoQueue.Status == ApoQueueStatus.Gerado.ToString() || apoQueue.Status == ApoQueueStatus.Enviado.ToString();
        this.KeyFigure = apoQueue.KeyFigure;
        this.PathFileGenerated = apoFileBL.GetFullPathApo(apoQueue, true);
    }

    public string KeyFigure { get; set; }
    public bool HaveInconsistencies { get; set; }
    public string PathFileGenerated { get; set; }
    public bool EnableExport { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Eu concordo com o Cigano que a abordagem parece boa, só não faria o construtor padrão privado já que toda vez que você cria um construtor com parâmetros, o construtor padrão vazio é desabilitado pelo compilador e não poderá ser chamado. Ainda seria possível criar um construtor sem parâmetros se quisesse, mas não parece ser o caso. Se não tivesse o construtor com parâmetros, e não quisesse que houvesse uma construção (raro), aí o construtor privado seria útil.

Isso pode ser comprovado nos códigos abaixo:

```
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var vmc = new ApoQueueVMConstrutor(); //construiu sem inicializar nada, mesmo sem ter sido declarado, o construtor está lá
        var vm1 = new ApoQueueVM("xxx", "yyy"); //construiu conforme o esperado
//      var vm2 = new ApoQueueVM(); //não existe construtor com esta assinatura
    }
}
 
public class ApoQueueVM {
    public ApoQueueVM(string apoQueue, string apoFileBL) {
        this.EnableExport = true;
        this.KeyFigure = apoQueue;
        this.PathFileGenerated = apoFileBL;
    }
 
    public string KeyFigure { get; set; }
    public bool HaveInconsistencies { get; set; }
    public string PathFileGenerated { get; set; }
    public bool EnableExport { get; set; }
}
 
public class ApoQueueVMConstrutor {
    public string KeyFigure { get; set; }
    public bool HaveInconsistencies { get; set; }
    public string PathFileGenerated { get; set; }
    public bool EnableExport { get; set; }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/nZTCJ7). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cucdzl). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ASP.NET/ViewModel2.cs).

Comment: Para o caso específico de *ViewModels*, não há a construção em nenhum outro lugar da aplicação que não seja necessariamente a *Action* do *Controller* dele, então a preocupação não é necessária. Agora, se estivéssemos falando de *Models* e até mesmo *Controllers*, aí concordo com você.