# Erro ao utilizar GROUP via LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, linq

Estou tentando realizar a consulta abaixo:

```
                var query = from s in db.Crm_Analise
                        where s.cliente_CRM == cod_cli
                        group s by s.TAG into g
                        select new
                        {
                            TAG = g.Key,
                            ATUALIZAÇÃO = g.Max(t => t.data_creat),
                            RELATÓRIOS = g.Count(t => t.modelo != null)
                        };
```

Porem, é apresentado o erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue a `View`:

```
   @model IEnumerable<OneeWeb_v3.Models.Crm_Analise>
@{
    ViewBag.title = "TAG's";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>    
</head>
<body>
    <h2>@ViewBag.title</h2> 

    <table class="table">
        <tr>          
            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("TAG", "Index")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("ATUALIZAÇÃO", "Index")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("RELATÓRIOS", "Index")
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TAG)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.data_creat)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.modelo)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Visualizar", "Details") 
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>

<ul class="pager">
    <li><a href="#">Anterior</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Proximo</a></li>
</ul>
```

Model:

```
 public class Crm_Analise
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string cod_item_CRM { get; set; }
    public string TAG { get; set; }
    public string data_creat { get; set; }
    public string modelo { get; set; }   
    public int cliente_CRM { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
        // GET: Crm_Analise
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        if (Session["cod_cli"] != null)
        {
            int cod_cli = Convert.ToInt32(Session["cod_cli"]);

            var query = from s in db.Crm_Analise
                        where s.cliente_CRM == cod_cli
                        select new
                        {
                            TAG = s.TAG,
                            ATUALIZAÇÃO = s.data_creat,
                            RELATÓRIOS = s.cod_item_CRM
                        };

            if (query.Count() > 0)
            {
                return View(await query.ToListAsync());
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { cod_cli = Session["cod_cli"], razao_social = Session["razao_social"] });
            }

        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
        }
    }
```

Sei que tem alguma coisa haver com `@model IEnumerable<OneeWeb_v3.Models.Crm_Analise>` mas nao sei como resolver..

Comment: o tipo enviado para View é diferente do que está em sua configuração, precisa criar um `ViewModel` quando é assim

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Obrigado. vou pesquisar sobre viewmodel

Comment: Cara, posta o método que você encapsula pro objeto da tela e manda o controller também pra ajudar... Provavelmente deve ser que você esteja enviando um objeto do tipo "A", mas na sua tela o "@model" espera o tipo B.

Comment: Exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/169742/onde-colocar-a-regra-da-view-model/169761#169761

Comment: @AyrtonGiffoni Atualização feita. obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tente alterar o seu select na query

```
var query = from s in db.Crm_Analise
    where s.cliente_CRM == cod_cli
    select new Crm_Analise()
    {
        TAG = s.TAG,
        data_creat = s.data_creat,
        cod_item_CRM = s.cod_item_CRM
    };
```

altere também o head da sua table, para ele não precisar ir no controller pegar o nome (faça isso somente se for necessário)

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>          
            <th>
                TAG
            </th>
            <th>
                Atualização
            </th>
            <th>
                Relatórios
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model) {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TAG)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.data_creat)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.modelo)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Visualizar", "Details") 
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```